# AWS Alarm not getting value from metric

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I havea  requirement to setup a CloudWatch alarm with `CPUUtilization` metric type for cluster and service dimensions. To setup these resources I am using CDK library and after deploy CDKstack things looks fine. Both alarm and metric are available in ECS cluster.

Following is piece of code that I am using for same.
Now when I increase CPU load using stress utility then this CDK code doesn't work but if I create alarm manually using AWS GUI then things work fine.

Can someone help me on this ?

```
export class HelloCdkStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "AlarmVpc3", {
       maxAzs: 3
     });

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, "AlarmClusterDemo3", {
       vpc: vpc,
       containerInsights: true,
       clusterName: "DemoCluster"
    });

    cluster.addCapacity('DefaultAutoScalingGroupCapacity', {
      instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType("t2.micro"),
    });

    const taskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, 'TaskDefDemo3', {
      // memoryLimitMiB: 512,
      // cpu: 256 
    });

    taskDefinition.addContainer('MyContainer', {
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry("amazon/amazon-ecs-sample"),
      memoryLimitMiB: 512,
    });

    // Instantiate an Amazon ECS Service
    const ecsService = new ecs.FargateService(this, 'ServiceDemo3', {
      serviceName: "DemoService",
      cluster,
      taskDefinition,
      enableExecuteCommand: true,
      desiredCount: 1
    });

    const cpuMetric = new cloudwatch.Metric({
      namespace: 'AWS/ECS ',
      metricName: 'CPUUtilization', //ECS/ContainerInsights
      period: Duration.minutes(1),
      dimensionsMap: {
        ServiceName: "AlarmCdk3-ServiceDemo3Service80A0F131-LofBYzFzUatv",
        ClusterName: "AlarmCdk3-AlarmClusterDemo3EF161BDA-jm7guu27s8bV"
      }
    });
    
    const cpuAlarm = new cloudwatch.Alarm(taskDefinition, 'CPUAlarmDemo', {
      alarmName: "DemoAlarm",
      metric: cpuMetric,
      threshold: 5,
      evaluationPeriods: 1,
      datapointsToAlarm: 1,
    });
    
  } 
}
```

Comment: I would try removing the trailing space here: `'AWS/ECS '`

Comment: removed the space but still not working.

Comment: Hi @gshpychka, its working fine. dimension wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Metric objects that the service [exposes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.FargateService.html#metricwbrcpuwbrutilizationprops):

`const cpuMetric = ecsService.metricCpuUtilization({period: Duration.minutes(1)});`